# Simple way to read variables on different lines from STDIN?

Tags: php

I want to read two integers on two lines like:

```
4
5
```

This code works:

```
fscanf(STDIN,"%d",$num);
fscanf(STDIN,"%d",$v);
```

But I wonder if there's a shorter way to write this? (For more variables, I don't want to write a statement for each variable) Like:

```
//The following two lines leaves the second variable to be NULL
fscanf(STDIN,"%d%d",$num,$v);
fscanf(STDIN,"%d\n%d",$num,$v);
```

**Update:** I solved this using the method provided in the answer to read an array and `list` to assign variables from an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this example:

```
<?php

$formatCatalog = '%d,%s,%s,%d';

$inputValues = [];
foreach (explode(',', $formatCatalog) as $formatEntry) {
  fscanf(STDIN, trim($formatEntry), $inputValues[]);
}

var_dump($inputValues);
```

When executing and feeding it with

```
1
foo
bar
4
```

you will get this output:

```
array(4) {
  [0] =>
  int(1)
  [1] =>
  string(3) "foo"
  [2] =>
  string(3) "bar"
  [3] =>
  int(4)
}
```

Bottom line: you certainly can use loops or similar for the purpose and this can shorten your code a bit. Most of all it simplifies its maintenance. However if you want to specify a format to read with each iteration, then you do need to specify that format somewhere. That is why shortening the code is limited...

---

Things are different if you do *not* want to handle different types of input formats. In that case you can use a generic loop:

```
<?php

$inputValues = [];
while (!feof(STDIN)) {
  fscanf(STDIN, '%d', $inputValues[]);
}

var_dump($inputValues);
```

Now if you feed this with

```
1
2
3
```

on standard input and then detach the input (by pressing CTRL-D for example), then the output you get is:

```
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  int(1)
  [1] =>
  int(2)
  [2] =>
  int(3)
}
```

The same code is obviously usable with input redirection, so you can feed a file into the script which makes detaching the standard input obsolete...

Answer (score 2):

If you can in your code, try to implement a array :

```
fscanf(STDIN, "%d\n", $n);

$num=array();
while($n--){
    fscanf(STDIN, "%d\n", $num[]);
}
print_r($num);
```